# How to add an identical navigation bar at the bottom of the page

Tags: 2013

I am interested in adding a navigation bar to the bottom of the page - one that is identical to my top navigation bar (Oslo master page). I've seen SharePoint themes with added links at the bottom of the page, but I'm not sure how they do it. Would I have to create a custom master page or can I edit the one that I am currently using?

I am also interested in adding an image on the right side of the navigation bar, above the search field. I want the image to be a clickable image that links to another page in the site.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally advisable to create a new master page, edit it, then apply it (via either Designer when right clicking on the file, or via Site Settings), just in case you stuff up the original.

Aside from that it's just a case of trial and error with editing the XHTML until you get the result you need... prepare for a lot of wailing and gnashing of teeth though...

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say create a new master page I mean create a copy of the existing one you're using, then just add the bits you need.

Comment: You mean I should edit the HTML file that corresponds to the master page that I'm using, correct?

Comment: Correct - I find it easiest in Designer. If you connect to the site, then go to Master Pages, and right click on the current one (Oslo) there is a 'Create New From Current Page' option which gives you a copy to play with.

I would create a copy of Oslo, then create a new site with the copy as it's master page, then you can edit to your hearts content and compare the two, and just restart if you break something.

Master pages are a bit delicate so it's wise to take due precaution when editing them.

Comment: Does SharePoint designer let you alter the master page through a GUI, or is it just like editing the HTML file in a text editor? I've been editing my master page's corresponding HTML file through notepad++ and it's difficult because I'm extremely new to HTML.

Comment: Only with a text interface I'm afraid - AFAIK there's no way to edit a master page like a normal site page. The HTML is nicely labelled and indented though.